# How to find button handle in a WPF application, and click it programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to programmaticly (from my own application) press a button that is located on another running windows (WPF) application.

Todo so, a handle to the button would be needed. There are plenty of posts about how to get such a handle.

However, it seem that WPF applications don't present handles for their graphical components:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25665615/Spy-or-Windows-Api-Functions-not-locating-controls-on-child-window.html

Any clues on how to achieve an automated press on a button in such an application?

I don't have control of the source code for the application with the button.

Comment: you will most likely need to inject yourself into the application and get a reference on the main window. Then recursively query thru children based on types. Wont be an easy task

Comment: I can get the handle to the window by FindWindow function, no problem.

Comment: If you have VS Enterprise, you can check out the Coded UI test feature, maybe that can help. It has the ability to find buttons in applications and then press them automatically, so maybe you can reproduce that automatism yourself. Just a hunch, though.

Comment: @Totte Karlsson   Having the hWnd, through an AutomationElement -> `AutomationElement.FromHandle`:  [AutomationElement Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement(v=vs.110).aspx). Then look at [LogicalTreeHelper Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: what I meant is a reference where your app is in the same virtual memory space as the WPF app

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll need to look into UI Automation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview

Comment: I don't have control of the source code for the application with the button.

Comment: I understand that you don't have source. UI Automation starts at the desktop and allows you to view the hierarchy of programs currently running. Perhaps look at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33049/WPF-UI-Automation for different description.